# Is there a wireless mouse which works on glass surfaces and wood surfaces?

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, wireless-mouse

Does anyone know of any wireless mouse **that has a wireless receiver**, and can work without a mouse pad on glass surfaces and wood surfaces, and is not too noisy especially when I click and scroll?

I'm currently using the [Logitech anywhere mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/mice-pointers/mice/devices/5846) and the problem is that it's way too noisy (when I click and even when I scroll) and besides it doesn't work on wood surfaces (so much for being *anywhere*).

**It doesn't need to be optical**

I'm willing to pay tons, i'm just worried now that no one sells these stuff in the globe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optical mice don't usually function correctly on these types of surfaces:

- **The problem with glass** is that the light passes through and doesn't reflect back to the mouse, so the mouse can't detect movement.
- **The problem with wooden surfaces** (at least for the unfinished or non-smoothed materials) is that the light reflects in unexpected directions, due to the inconsistency of the wood fibres, and so the mouse can't detect the movement accurately.

The types of mice that work better on these surfaces have a ball instead of an optical sensor.  If Logitech isn't producing a current wireless-with-ball model (I couldn't find any on their web site that are wireless, although their sales team may be able to help you with this), you may be able to purchase a used model from someone through a web site like eBay -- when wireless mice were new, optical mice weren't on the market yet (or at least they weren't popular due to fairly high initial pricing) as I remember, so these models do exist (I also remember using one many years ago).

[image]
[image]

Pictured above is **Logitech M-RN68 Cordless Mouse** featuring a PS/2 connector and a ball (as opposed to having an *optical* light and sensor).  More information, including specifications, are available on this web page:  http://www.tcocd.de/Pictures/Peripheral/Logitech/mrn68.shtml

Comment: btw if balls are better what is the reason for the optical mouse hype?

Comment: @Pacerier:  Both have advantages -- the main one is that the ball needs to be cleaned periodically (based on usage, the user's sweat output, dirt and dust in the local vicinity, etc.) whereas the lasers rarely seem to need any cleaning at all.  In school settings, a common problem was that the balls kept going missing (and the students were always surprised that anyone would ever think of stealing one, heheh), and the move to laser mice resolved this problem.  I suspect the production costs may be lower too because fewer materials are needed.  A laser mouse also works better in a zero-gravity.

Comment: oic. so basically, am i right to say that it boils down to the only disadvantage is that it needs to be cleaned periodically? if so around how long do you mean by periodically? like once a year or once a month?

Comment: @Pacerier:  This is not the only disadvantage (as I pointed out in my un-edited comment).  Periodically is a vague term that I used intentionally as it is effected by various conditions such as perspiration, amounts of dust, usage, etc. (as I also pointed out in the same un-edited comment).  I know people who had to clean their balls weekly because they perspire so much, yet I rarely (after many years) had to clean mine.

Comment: btw you mean "cordless" as "wireless" right? so basically to use that wireless mouse i'd still have to attach a wire receiver to it.. ?

Comment: @Pacerier:  That's correct (good question, +1) -- for any wireless (or cordless) device to be useful, it needs to communicate with the computer somehow which requires that the computer have a receiver.  (Some modern devices will utilize a BlueTooth transceiver, but aside from many modern laptops most computers don't have this built-in.  The mouse I suggested doesn't utilize BlueTooth, and comes with its own receiver/transceiver device.)

Comment: ok so basically you are saying those with balls all need wires? or there exists, those with balls and have wireless receivers?

Comment: @Pacerier:  No.  Whether the mouse has a ball or a laser motion sensor it doesn't matter -- either can be wireless (or "cordless") or rely on a wired connection.  But, it just happened to be that wireless/cordless mice were far less common when mice with balls were the common technology (laser motion sensors are a newer technology, and were introduced into the market after wireless/cordless mice were already on the market).